# unique combinations of subgroups across all groups in selected columns in pandas data frame and their count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, analytics

I have data of tenders and bidders. I want to find the set of bidders (let's say set of 2 bidders), bidding in different tenders along with bidding count of such sets.
I have the following data:

```
data={'Tender_id':['T1','T1','T1','T1','T1','T1','T1','T1','T1','T1','T2','T2','T2','T2','T2','T2','T2','T2','T2','T2','T3','T3','T3','T3','T3','T3','T3','T3','T3','T3','T4','T4','T4','T4','T4','T4','T4','T4','T4','T4','T5','T5','T5','T5','T5','T5','T5','T5','T5','T5'], 'Bidder_id':['B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B8','B9','B10','B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B8','B9','B10','B11','B1','B2','B3','B14','B15','B16','B7','B92','B9','B1','B91','B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B17','B18','B19','B10','B1','B2','B93','B14','B15','B16','B17','B18','B19','B10']}

df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

which looks like this:

```
Index Tender_ID Bidder_ID
0         T1        B1
1         T1        B2
2         T1        B3
3         T1        B4
4         T1        B5
5         T1        B6
6         T1        B7
7         T1        B8
8         T1        B9
9         T1       B10
10        T2        B2
11        T2        B3
12        T2        B4
13        T2        B5
14        T2        B6
15        T2        B7
16        T2        B8
17        T2        B9
18        T2       B10
19        T2       B11
20        T3        B1
21        T3        B2
22        T3        B3
23        T3       B14
24        T3       B15
25        T3       B16
26        T3        B7
27        T3       B92
28        T3        B9
29        T3        B1
30        T4       B91
31        T4        B2
32        T4        B3
33        T4        B4
34        T4        B5
35        T4        B6
36        T4       B17
37        T4       B18
38        T4       B19
39        T4       B10
40        T5        B1
41        T5        B2
42        T5       B93
43        T5       B14
44        T5       B15
45        T5       B16
46        T5       B17
47        T5       B18
48        T5       B19
49        T5       B10
```

I tried to make all unique combination of two bidders in each tender by using this code:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([
    [n, x, y]
    for n, g in df.groupby('Tender_ID').Bidder_ID
    for x, y in combinations(g, 2)
], columns=['Tender', 'sgm_1', 'sgm_2'])
df2 = df1.groupby(['sgm_1', 'sgm_2']).size().reset_index(name="count")
df3 = df2[(df2['sgm_1']!=df2['sgm_2'])]
new_df = pd.merge(df1, df2,  how='left', left_on=['sgm_1','sgm_2'], right_on = ['sgm_1','sgm_2'])

print (new_df)
```

which gave me the following result:

```
    Tender sgm_1 sgm_2  count
0       T1    B1    B2      3
1       T1    B1    B3      2
2       T1    B1    B4      1
3       T1    B1    B5      1
4       T1    B1    B6      1
..     ...   ...   ...    ...
220     T5   B17   B19      2
221     T5   B17   B10      2
222     T5   B18   B19      2
223     T5   B18   B10      2
224     T5   B19   B10      2
```

But it is showing same bidders set across different tenders, such as

[image]

However, my intended result is like this:
[image: Intended results]

May somebody help me to get the desired results.

Comment: I don't know how you can get 2 counts of B1/B2 for T1.

Comment: @mozway may be after getting the result, something can be done to again perform summerization or anything else.

Comment: you can do anything you want, but the logic is currently unclear